# move folder and subfolders to mounted cifs share

Tags: mv, cifs

I am trying to move the main folder (which is the date), and specific subfolders and files to a mounted `cifs` drive (test).

```
mv -v bam,bed /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-10-2016 smb://smb/smbdatabay/test
mv: cannot move ‘/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-10-2016’ to ‘smb://smb/smbdatabay/file’: No such file or directory
```

I can manually see all the folders and the share.  Thank you :).

**Structure of directory to move** (need to move bam and bed and subfolders)

```
6-10-2016
bam
- file
- test
bed
id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination must be the mount point (folder without prefix smb:/). From man:

```
NAME
       mv - move (rename) files

SYNOPSIS
       mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

DESCRIPTION
       Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
...
```